# Laravel E-com delivery charges by calculate between kilometer

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

may I know is it possible the shipping fees is calculated by kilometer within a distance from my coordinate location?

For example, i already set a coordinate location that would be my physical store, and my shipping area only can deliver within 20 kilometer from my location.

How am i suppose to let customer can only choose the shipping area within 20 km from my location, and set a shipping fees on it?

Please help. Much appreciated and thank you all.

Comment: 20 km on road or by "air"?

Comment: I believe the easiest way is to use post code. It won't be 20 km exact, it could be 25 somewhere and 19 on other places. But it's just a matter of hard coding it in. It will take an hour perhaps, but starting from scratch and using Google maps API to get distances and all that will probably take longer.

Comment: 20km by road, is it at shipping area there to let customer select certain post code?

Comment: because i still no idea how the algorithm should run

Comment: If you want to go by rough numbers then post code is a good option, but it does not work well if the store moves or if you want to scale the delivery from 20 km to 30 km. I can write a answer with post code and rough numbers if you want it.

Comment: let customer search for a location to be delivered within the 20 KM. you can chose the locations surronded by 20km using google map APIs.(https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). and get the location from customer then calculate the distance from you store to client location, the calculate the fee accordingly.

Comment: yeah can i have the answer? thank you so much! @Andreas

Comment: hmm, i will take a look in it, thank you for your suggestion @SandeepSudhakaran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need rough numbers and don't care if it's 20 or 23 km then you can use post codes.
If you want to you can "fine tune" each post code with street, and if needed with house number.

```
$UserPostCode = 12345;
$UserStreet = "3-street";

$Postcodes = [
              "11111" => [
                           "A-street" => 12,
                           "B-street" => 10,
                           "C-street" => 15,
                           "Default"  => 11
                         ],
               "12345" => [
                            "1-street" => 5,
                            "2-street" => 6,
                            "3-street" => 7,
                            "Default"  => 5
                         ]
             ];

if(isset($PostCodes[$UserPostCode])){
    // post code is within your range
    if(isset($PostCodes[$UserPostCode][$UserStreet])){
        // you have a price set for this street
        echo $PostCodes[$UserPostCode][$UserStreet]; //7
    }else{
        // This is a new street in the postcode unknown to you, give default price
        echo $PostCodes[$UserPostCode]["Default"];
    }
}else{
    // customer lives out of range
    echo "Sorry can't deliver to you";
}
```

As I wrote above you can fine tune the streets to house number 1-50 and 50 and higher if you like with the same logic as above.